# How to move the horizontal bar on SSMS with mouse wheel?

Tags: scroll, ssms

If I use the Azure Data Studio than I can move the horizontal bar with the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Mouse Wheel.

Why this is not possible on SSMS? Is it possible to activate it?

Answer (score 0):

On my mouse I am able to push the wheel to the left or right to scroll. Give that a shot :)

It is a standard Dell mouse.